# Get Country Code & Show Different Welcome Message

Tags: json

I'm beginner & trying to make a welcome message for my blog which show different statement for different countries visitor.
Right now i'm doing this & its working fine.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
       <style>.cntcod{display:none;}</style> 

    <div id="welcome1" class="cntcod">Welcome, Italian!</div>
    <div id="welcome2" class="cntcod">Welcome, Canada!</div>
    <div id="welcome3" class="cntcod">Welcome, German!</div>
    <div id="welcome4" class="cntcod">Welcome,</div>

$.get("https://ipinfo.io", function(response) {
if(response.country == "IT") {
    $("#welcome1").show();
}
else if(response.country == "CA") {
    $("#welcome2").show();
}
else if(response.country == "DE") {
    $("#welcome3").show();
}
else {
    $("#welcome4").show();
}}, "jsonp");
```

But problem is Ipinfo.io only allows 1000 requests/day.So i tried to use this [freegeoip.net](http://freegeoip.net/json/).But every time i replace

```
 `$.get("https://ipinfo.io", function(response) {`
```

with

`$.get("http://freegeoip.net/json/", function(response) {`

it show nothing.Like something is missing or i'm not doing it properly.I tied my best but i can't get it.
It would be nice if some one guide me or give me some hint.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the browser console for errors. // Btw., just because I perhaps happened to visit your site while currently being in Italy, doesn’t necessarily mean I speak Italian ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just replaced that line its because the answer of freegeoip doesn't give you the 'country' attribute. There it's called 'country_name'. And in my case for example, the answer doesn't contain any value for country_name, i just get lat and lon.

Comment: Will you please take a look here https://jsfiddle.net/LaStOpTioN/1r67bjgv/1/
I tried to change 'country' attribute to 'country_code' but not worked for me.Sorry if i cause you trouble.

Comment: {"ip":"52.56.61.249","country_code":"GB","country_name":"United Kingdom","region_code":"ENG","region_name":"England","city":"London","zip_code":"EC4N","time_zone":"Europe/London","latitude":51.5092,"longitude":-0.0955,"metro_code":0}

Comment: Thanks a lot sir.

Comment: If you have a lot of these welcome statements you should consider to use a dictionary to avoid a too big 'if else' struct and too much <div>'s.
e.g.: https://jsfiddle.net/1r67bjgv/5/